# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre bucle y cliclo en Grafos?

Tags: teoría-de-grafos

No entiendo la diferencia entre bucle y ciclo dentro de un grafo. La diapositiva de los apuntes no explica exactamente la diferencia.

Answer (score 1):

- Un bucle es un nodo del grafo que esta unido consigo mismo. Ej vértice 1
- Un ciclo es un camino cerrado, es decir, un conjunto de vértices unidos en el que ÚNICAMENTE se pasa 1 VEZ por cada uno excepto el primer nodo que se pasaría dos veces (la de inicio y la de fin). Ej: Un camino ahí sería (2,3,4,5,2). Para que lo veas más fácil es como si tuvieras que dibujar un polígono pasando por los puntos, sin levantar el lápiz y sin pasar dos veces por el mismo sitio. Por ejemplo la ruta (6,4,3,2,5,4,6) no es un camino porque estas pasando dos veces por el 4. El 6 da igual dado que el único punto que puedes repetir es por el que empiezas a dibujar el camino

Espero que te sirva. Un saludo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]